# If $K$ is a field of characteristic $2$ and $G$ is a group with $2$ elements, then $K[G]\cong K[x]/x^2$, and this has a unique maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I tried to map $ae+bf$ to $a + bx$ where $G = \{e,f\}$, but it seems that $K[G]$ and $K[x]/x^2$ are isomorphic as groups but not as rings (and $K[G]\cong K[x]/(x^2-1)$) by this map. I can't think of another possible mapping, any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you already know that elements of $\operatorname{K}[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$ are of the form: $k_1+k_2x$ for $k_1,k_2\in \operatorname{K}$. Now what do elements of $\operatorname{K}[G]$ look like? Maybe you can construct an isomorphism between the two fields when you realize how the elements of both look like.

Comment: @Fotis Thank you for your response! I read more, and tried to construct an isomorphism, but it seems not an isomorphism between the two rings.

Comment: $K[x]/x^2$ has an element whose square is zero, namely, $x$. Can you find an element of $K[G]$ whose square is zero?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your reminding! I seem to have found the map.

Comment: Good. Please share!

Comment: In general, $K[G] \simeq K[x] / \langle x^2 - 1 \rangle$.  But if $K$ has characteristic 2, then $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)^2$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of two elements, namely $G=\left\{e,g\right\}$ (I prefer to write $g$ for the non identity element rather than $f$ like you did, but that's just personal preference).

As you correctly pointed out, any element of the ring $K[G]$ is of the form $ae+bg$, for $a,b\in K$.
On the other hand, as I said in the comments, any element of $K[x]/x^2$ is of the form $k_1+k_2x$ for $k_1,k_2\in K$.
Finally, notice that $g^2=e=1$ in $K[G]$, while $x^2=0$ in $K[x]/x^2$, so sending $g$ to $x$ wouldn't really make sense.

But also notice that $(x+1)^2=x^2+1=1$ in $K[x]/x^2$ since $K$ has characteristic $2$. (This is in a sense the "dual" of what @Gerry Myerson suggests to do, instead of finding in $K[G]$ an element that squares to $0$, we find in $K[x]/x^2$ a (non-trivial) element that squares to $1$)

With this information, a very good guess for an isomorphism between the two rings, would be a map that sends $e$ to $1$ and $g$ to $1+x$, or if we extend this thought, the map:
$$f:K[G]\rightarrow K[x]/x^2$$
$$f(ae+bg)=a+b(1+x)=(a+b)+bx$$

Before we try to prove that this map defines an isomorphism, we should first show that it is a morphism!
Actually we should also show that this is a well defined map, but if this isn't obvious enough, I leave it up to you to prove it.

So, in order to first show that a map is a morphism, we should show that it respects the operations of the two rings, and depending on some authors, that it sends the identity of the first ring to that of the second.

Let $a_1e+b_1g, a_2e+b_2g$ be two elements of $K[G]$.

Again, I'll leave up to you to show the easier result that indeed we have:

$$f\left((a_1e+b_1g)+(a_2e+b_2g)\right)=f(a_1e+b_1g)+f(a_2e+b_2g)$$
i.e. that $f$ respects addition.

I'll prove that $f$ also respects multiplication, namely that:

$$f\left((a_1e+b_1g)\cdot(a_2e+b_2g)\right)=f(a_1e+b_1g)\cdot f(a_2e+b_2g)$$

Indeed, note that:

$$(a_1e+b_1g)\cdot(a_2e+b_2g)=a_1a_2e+a_1b_2g+b_1a_2g+b_1b_2g^2$$
$$=(a_1a_2+b_1b_2)e+(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)g$$
so:

$$f((a_1e+b_1g)\cdot(a_2e+b_2g))=f((a_1a_2+b_1b_2)e+(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)g)$$
$$=(a_1a_2+b_1b_2+a_1b_2+b_1a_2)+(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)x$$

and

$$f(a_1e+b_1g)\cdot f(a_2e+b_2g)=((a_1+b_1)+b_1x)\cdot((a_2+b_2)+b_2x)$$
$$=(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)+(a_1+b_1)b_2x+b_1(a_2+b_2)x$$
$$=(a_1a_2+b_1b_2+a_1b_2+b_1a_2)+a_1b_2x+b_1a_2x+2b_1b_2x$$
$$=(a_1a_2+b_1b_2+a_1b_2+b_1a_2)+(a_1b_2+b_1a_2)x$$

where we used the fact that $x^2=0$ and that $\operatorname{char}(K)=2$.

So indeed we get that $f$ respects both addition and multiplication, and it is pretty obvious that it sends the identity of the first ring to that of the second by the way we defined the map.
Hence we have done the hard part of the job, proving that $f$ defines a morphism.

Now we have the easy part left, show that $f$ is "$1$-$1$" and onto.
This is pretty trivial to show, so I won't prove it, but I'll note that in order to show that it is "$1$-$1$", all you need to see is that $1$ and $1+x$ are linearly independent.

Thus we have achieved what we wanted, an isomorphism of rings between $K[G]$ and $K[x]/x^2$!

Now to adress the unique maximal ideal, note that since $K$ is a field, $K[x]$ is a PID and so $K[x]/x^2$ is a PID.

We have that $x$ is an irreducible element of $K[x]/x^2$ and since we are in a PID, $\langle x\rangle$ is prime and hence maximal.
To prove uniqueness, let $I=\langle a+bx\rangle$, for $a,b\in K$ be another ideal with $a\neq 0$ (for if $a=0$, the two ideals would be the same).

Then $x(a+bx)\in I\Rightarrow ax+bx^2\in I\Rightarrow ax\in I\Rightarrow x\in I$ (since $K$ is a field and so $a^{-1}\in K$).
And hence, $bx\in I\Rightarrow bx+(a+bx)=a+2bx=a\in I\Rightarrow 1\in I\Rightarrow I=K[x]/x^2$.

Thus any other ideal is either equal to $\langle x\rangle$ or the entire ring, proving the uniqueness of it.